# Is there a way to upload a file to the database after changing it to a suitable model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to make admin page if admin user upload file (like csv file format and so on), it save in database after changing suitable model. For example, suppose a user uploads the following file.

```
year month survived ticket
2002  08      1     cn-101
2001  09      0     cn-102
2002  11      1     cn-103
```

What I want to make is when user upload this file in admin page, it change file to model like below and save in database.

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
   year = models.IntegerField()
   month = models.IntegerField()
   survived = models.booleanField()
   ticket = models.CharField()
```

It there any way to do this in Django???

Comment: There's no built-in functionality in django's admin app that works this way. However it's fairly easy to write a view that lets you create model instances from a csv file. This is a kind of api view. What you need to consider is what happens if you post the same data twice. Should you add more rows to the database, or should duplicates be ignored. Should there be an error message?

Comment: Thank you for your advice ! And if admin user post the same data, I want to make duplicates be ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit `save_model` method as below

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class SampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    file_path = request.FILES['myfile']
    with open(file_path) as f:
      for line in f:
        year, month, survived, ticket = f.split()
        SampleModel.objects.create(year=year, 
                                   month=month, 
                                   survived=bool(int(survived)), 
                                   ticket=ticket)
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```